# Do I need to submit the app again after changed app layout by using react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

As I know react native is using js for development, so that do i need to resubmit the app to app store , after i changed the layout or function everytime, or it can change it like a webview without submit app?

Comment: Javascript then communicates with native components through bridges. So if you change something in JS which affects the native components, then you have to rebuild a new version and resubmit. You can do different things though - you can fetch your configuration from a server and thus there won't be a need for redoing the app, as it will handle multiple alternatives already, which would then be decided on the serverside.

Answer (score 0):

This featuer is available if you use `CodePush` https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push

Or if you use `Expo` https://docs.expo.io/workflow/publishing/